# Why does the F-4's rear seat have a weather scope eyepiece?

Tags: cockpit, feature-identification, f-4

In the front seat. The pilot has a flat screen radar scope that shows both the planes and the weather.

But on the rear seat. The weather scope has an giant eyepiece. Perhaps glare protection?

[image]
([angelfire.com](http://www.angelfire.com/dc/jinxx1/Phantoms/F4bits.html))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's not an eyepiece, it's a glare shield. The angle of the display made it susceptible to glare from light entering the cockpit. The shield made it easier to see, at night as well. My theory is that they got the idea from Star Trek. Spock had one too on his workstation on the Enterprise.

Comment: I don’t know if Mr. Spock will consider “Emojis” fascinating. But I hope Kirk will fight them!

Comment: Kirk would never fight emojis, he would seduce them.

Comment: Maybe an F-4 backseater can tell us how they kept from puking their guts out as they looked through the glareshield while the aircraft was maneuvering. That had to be a totally gut-snarking thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

It was for glare but it was also a nice cushion for my face to smack into when an FNG pilot unexpectedly g’d up the jet while I was in the radar.